# How can I order objects according to some attribute of the child in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is the situation: I have a parent model say `BlogPost`. It has many `Comment`s. What I want is the list of `BlogPost`s ordered by the creation date of its' `Comment`s. I.e. the blog post which has the most newest comment should be on top of the list. Is this possible with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/mappers.html#controlling-ordering

> As of version 0.5, the ORM does not
>   generate ordering for any query unless
>   explicitly configured.
>
> The “default” ordering for a
>   collection, which applies to
>   list-based collections, can be
>   configured using the order_by keyword
>   argument on relation():

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question as the parent when using the ORM, and GHZ's link contained the answer on how it's possible. In sqlalchemy, assuming BlogPost.comments is a mapped relation to the Comments table, you can't do:

> session.query(BlogPost).order_by(BlogPost.comments.creationDate.desc())

, but you can do:

> session.query(BlogPost).join(Comments).order_by(Comments.creationDate.desc())